# Is it acceptable to say "the why"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, articles

Is it proper English to say, *The why*? An example:

> I need to find out the why.

To me, *the*, doesn't belong in this sentence.

---

Note: TV personality Dr. Oz often says "the why".

Comment: “If you know the why, you can live any how.” ― _Friedrich Nietzsche_

Comment: @ermanen I wouldn't be so quick to cite translated German, personally. I mean, you're ending up in the right place, but the route is suspect. :P

Comment: "When in the why and the wherefore is neither rhyme
nor reason?" ― _Shakespeare_

Answer (score 7):

It's a fairly common and not unacceptable usage of a wh-word as a noun.

From the internet [tidied]:

> Elise shares the “which” and the “why” of her “go-to” library.
>
> From the sober abstract that clearly stated the what, the which, and
>   the why, she showed her hope of finding further evidence that supports
>   the view ...

Nowadays, the 'scare quotes' to acknowledge a risky usage would not be considered necessary by many people.

Comment: Not just 'nowadays': in 1878 Gilbert wrote "Never mind the why and wherefore" without quotes.

Comment: Gilbert's usages were assumed risky _unless_ put in scare quotes.

Comment: True. Not a writer who frightened easily.

Comment: Since a relative clause starting with the relative pronoun _why_ can only modify the noun _reason(s)_, saying _the why_ means _the reason(s)_.